# how to copy only a part of .CSV based on first column elements with java

Tags: java

[copy part like this(from date to date)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/496fP.png) I am trying to copy only a part of .CSV file based on the first column  (Start Date and Time) data looks like (2019-01-28  10:22:00 AM) but the user have to put it like this (2019/01/28 10:22:00)

this is for windows, java opencsv , this is what I found but dont do what I need exaclty :

like this:

int startLine = get value1 from column csv ;
int endLine = get value2 from column csv;

```
public static void showLines(String fileName, int startLine, int endLine) throws IOException  {
    String line = null;
    int currentLineNo = 1;
//  int startLine = 20056;//40930;
//  int currentLineNo = 0;
    File currentDirectory = new File(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
    String fromPath = currentDirectory.getCanonicalPath() + "\\Target\\part.csv";
    PrintWriter pw = null;

        pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fromPath), true);
        //pw.close();
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(fileName));

        //read to startLine
        while(currentLineNo<startLine) {
            if (in.readLine()==null) {
                // oops, early end of file
                throw new IOException("File too small");
            }
            currentLineNo++;
        }

        //read until endLine
        while(currentLineNo<=endLine) {
            line = in.readLine();
            if (line==null) {
                // here, we'll forgive a short file
                // note finally still cleans up
                return;
            }
            System.out.println(line);
            currentLineNo++;
            pw.println(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {


        System.out.println("Problem reading file.\n" + ex.getMessage());

    }finally {
        try { if (in!=null) in.close();
        pw.close();
        } catch(IOException ignore) {}
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    int startLine = 17 ;
    int endLine = 2222;
    File currentDirectory = new File(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        showLines(currentDirectory.getCanonicalPath() +  "\\Sources\\concat.csv", startLine, endLine);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
//  pw.println();
```

}

Comment: Sorry, I thought you said you used [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), but I see no use of opencsv in that code. Try again, this time using the opencsv library to parse the file.

Comment: sorry .. yes I used opencsv to define lineNumber in another class but that dosnt work ..  if (nextLine[0].contains("2019/04/01 23:54:00") )
         
         //int pos1 =nextLine[0].indexOf("2019/04/01 23:54");
         System.out.println( pos1);

Comment: This Question is not clear. Please revise to get better focused on a specific issue. And search Stack Overflow before posting. Parsing CSV has been adresses *many* times already. Explain how your Question is distinct from the many existing ones. If not different, delete or mark duplicate while linking to an original.

Comment: I think my question is clear .. I want to copy only a part of a huge .CSV   .. with that method I displayed I can do that but based on index of lines .. what I am looking for is to base on the first column[0] to copy that part of .csv ... I mean I will give my method two values from the first column[0] and then it will copy all lines between thoses two values  ..

Answer (score 0):

Common CSV format uses a comma as a delimiter, with quotations used to escape any column entry that uses them within the data. Assuming that your column one data is consistent with the format you posted, and that I wouldn't have to bother with quotations marks therefor, you could read the columns as:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //This is the path to the file you are writing to
    String targetPath = "";
    //This is the path to the file you are reading from
    String inputFilePath = "";
    String line = null;
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    boolean add = false;
    String startLine = "2019/01/28 10:22:00";
    String endLine = "2019/01/28 10:30:00";

    String addFlagSplit[] = startLine.replace("/", "-").split(" ");
    String addFlag = addFlagSplit[0] + " " + addFlagSplit[1];

    String endFlagSplit[] = endLine.replace("/", "-").split(" ");
    String endFlag = endFlagSplit[0] + " " + endFlagSplit[1];

    try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(targetPath), true)){
        try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFilePath))){
            while((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                String date = line.split(",")[0];
                if(date.contains(addFlag)) {
                    add = true;
                }else if(date.contains(endFlag)) {
                    break;
                }
                if(add) {
                    lines.add(line);
                }
            }
        }
        for(String currentLine : lines) {
            pw.append(currentLine + "\n");
        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196676/discussion-on-answer-by-omoshiroiii-how-to-copy-only-a-part-of-csv-based-on-fir).

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            File currentDirectory = new File(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
String targetPath = currentDirectory.getCanonicalPath() + "\\Target\\part.csv";
String inputFilePath = currentDirectory.getCanonicalPath() +  "\\Sources\\concat.csv";
            String line = null;
            ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
            boolean add = false;
            String startLine = "2019/01/28 10:22:00";
            String endLine = "2019/04/06 10:30:00";
           try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(targetPath), true)){
 try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFilePath))){
                    while((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                        String date = line.split(",")[0];
                        if(date.contains(startLine)) {
                            add = true;
                        }else if(date.contains(endLine)) {
                            break;
                        }
                        if(add) {
                            lines.add(line);
                        }
                    }
                }
                for(String currentLine : lines) {
                    pw.append(currentLine + "\n");
                }
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
```

Comment: So now I can control the startLine and the endLine by a calendar in Gui